# unable to map incoming json to pojo by rest controller spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

```
"{
  "id": 2,
  "type": "semiservice",
  "description": "semiservice",
  "services": [
    {
      "id": 39,
      "dateOfService": "2020-06-03",
      "vehicleId": 12345,
      "orderNum": "demoordernum123",
      "driverId": "driverid123",
      "vendorName": "vendorspdas",
      "issueId": "issueid123"
    }
  ]
}"
```

This is my JSON sent from UI. There is a `"` before `{` . How to remove it while making a post request by a react axios. Else can I handle it from my restcontroller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveService/", consumes={"application/json"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Services> saveService(@RequestBody Services services, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    LOGGER.info("Creating Service : {}", services);
    serviceService.saveService(services);
    return new ResponseEntity<Services>(services, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}


public class Services implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
//@JsonManagedReference
@JsonBackReference
private Servicetype servicetype;
private Date dateOfService;
private int vehicleId;
private String orderNum;
private String driverId;
private String vendorName;
private String issueId;


public class Servicetype implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
private String type;
private String description;
@JsonManagedReference
@JsonIgnore
private List<Services> services = new ArrayList<Services>();
```

Comment: this is json string, you need to convert string to json object

Comment: show `Services` class

Comment: @user7294900 added services

Comment: There are different fields from JSON, where's type and description for example

Comment: added the 2 entities

Comment: What error you get when the REST service is called with this json?